# Python make an efficient Grid with an extent

Tags: python, memory, grid, storage

I make a fonction in Python.
This function created a grid from a given extent with coordinates.

In enter you give :
envelope `(xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax)`

xDist distance in X for each mesh

yDist distance in Y for each mesh

In exit the fucntion give 2 lists

xResutl is the X coordinate for each mesh

yResult is the Y coordinate for each mesh

My code is :

```
from math import *

def distanceEuclidean(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    return sqrt( (x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2 )

def makeGrid(envelope, distX, distY):
    nbMeshX = int(ceil(distanceEuclidean(envelope[0], 0, envelope[1], 0)/distX))
    nbMeshY = int(ceil(distanceEuclidean(envelope[2], 0, envelope[3], 0)/distY))
    nbMesh = nbMeshX*nbMeshY
    xResult, yResult = range(nbMesh), range(nbMesh)
    count = 0
    for x in xrange(nbMeshX):
        for y in xrange(nbMeshY):
            x1 = envelope[0]+x*distX
            x2 = envelope[0]+(x+1)*distX
            y1 = envelope[2]+y*distY
            y2 = envelope[2]+(y+1)*distY
            xResult[count], yResult[count] =[x1,x2,x2,x1,x1], [y1, y1, y2, y2, y1]
    count += 1

    return xResult, yResult
```

When I use a little envelope it ok !But when I use a very large envelope the function is very slow, the result's list is very large, very slow and use a lot of memory.

For example :

With a tiny envelope :

Input :

```
envelope = [-10, 10, -15, 25]
print makeGrid(envelope, 20, 15)
```

Output :

```
 >>> ([[-10, 10, 10, -10, -10], [-10, 10, 10, -10, -10], [-10, 10, 10, -10, -10]], [[-15, -15, 0, 0, -15], [0, 0, 15, 15, 0], [15, 15, 30, 30, 15]])
```

With a very large envelope :

Input :

```
envelope = [47300, 1198000, 1617200, 2677500]
print makeGrid(envelope, 100, 100)
```

Output :

```
>>> MemoryError
```

Do you have any solution to reduce time computation and/or memory storage ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: math.ceil(x)

    Return the ceiling of x as a float, the smallest integer value greater than or equal to x.

Comment: using your values, it looks like you are trying to make a list that == `range(122008721)` values in it.. twice in the line: `xResult, yResult = range(nbMeshX*nbMeshY), range(nbMeshX*nbMeshY)`. which errors on my computer also.i was playign with it, and i found that it doenst error if you only do it once. maybe try ONLY calculating xResult first, and then yResult?

Comment: yeah It's a very very large arrray